# ruby mongoid query using regexp

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I've trying to do a mongoid query in my rails project. I thought this should work but it returns RegexpError: unmatched close parenthesis: /)/i
This is my attempt

```
search = params[:name]
users = User.any_of({first_name: /#{search}/i}, { last_name: /#{search}/i}).to_a
```

I really dont know what I'm doing wrong. Any help appreciated

Comment: Use `/#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i`

Comment: Thanks! It works perfect. I have just realized the issue raised because someone did a search with parameters ")" . So mongo was treating it as parenthesis instead of as string. Thanks a lot!